# Is there anyway to produce realistic load(cpu,memory and disk all together) on a linux system?

Tags: linux, benchmarking, memory-usage, disk-activity, cpu-load

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` and I want to stress test my system but most of benchmarks are specific in nature. Either they are benchmarking Disk or CPU or Memory usage etc. But is there anything which can generate load like the real systems do i.e CPU,Memory and Disk all together.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [Passmark burn in test for linux](http://www.passmark.com/products/bitlinux.htm). They provide a 30 day evaluation which may suit your needs. An alternative would be to run stress tests for each of the components at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use *parallel*:

```
 parallel -j 3 -- test1 test2 test3
```

This will run the three specific tests, *test[1-3]*, simultaneously.

If you want to extend that, you may write a small script which keeps executing each test as soon as it has finished:

```
 while true; do test1; done
```

This will give you a (theoretically infinite) long stretch of time over which your system is stressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the utility stress {[link](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/)}

If you more interested in stress-testing the hardware (as opposed to how Ubuntu handles a heavy load), try running Stresslinux {[link](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)}.